# How to modify Hybris Backoffice refocus functionality

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm trying to modify the backoffice refocusing functionality. Not sure exactly where the behavior is taking place but I believe the class is the *FocusUtils.java* (com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.util) This util class is used in the *DefaultEditorAreaValidationHandler.onEvent()*.

The action takes place in the summary-view of a product in the "Data Quality" section. Here the user can see what fields are missing or are needing to be filled. They can click on the attribute listed and the editor will refocus on the selected field. Currently the refocusing is working with the OOTB implementation BUT it cuts off the label to the fields at times. I would like to slightly modify this util class (override) and use the custom implementation instead.

[Field label is cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B43fB.jpg)

What should be dispalyed instead:

[Field label is displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP9si.jpg)

The only way to do this from what I can see is by modifying/replacing the widget implementation that is using this logic. Basededitorarea widget (com\hybris\cockpitng\widgets\baseeditorarea) and specifically having to override bean definition of the below bean and additional classes as well.

```
<alias name="defaultEditorAreaValidationPopupDelegate" alias="editorAreaValidationPopupDelegate" />
```

This is the only bean I see that is defined in the backoffice-widgets-spring.xml that eventually touches this focus logic. This is like the starting point. Ideally, it would be nice to just make changes to the actual util class or replace it with a custom one rather than having to duplicate many other classes.

Does anyone know if this is the correct approach to doing this? or if anyone has any alternative suggestions that would be great.